# How to fix "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a program that draws many circles at random positions in Python.
It breaks and spits a "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

I tried to increase the recursion limit but the python shell crushes and restarts

```
class Game():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self. root = root
        self.c = Canvas(root, bg = 'white')
        self.ball = []
        self.start = 0
        self.elapsed = 0
        self.time = 0
        self.i = 0
        self.root.bind('<Key>', self.key)
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        self.start = time.perf_counter()
        for self.i in range(200):
            self.ball.append([Balls(self.c)])
            Balls.create_balls(self)
        self.elapsed = time.perf_counter()
        self.time = self.elapsed - self.start
        print(self.time)
        self.c.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.root.after(30, self.update)

    def key(self, event):
        if event.char == 'c':
            #self.ball[57] = self.c.create_oval(Balls.x-12, Balls.y-12, Balls.x+12, Balls.y+12, fill = 'red')
            pass

class Balls(Game):

    def __init__(self, c):
        super(Balls, self).__init__(c)
        self.c = c
        self.x = random.randint(50.0, 450.0)
        self.y = random.randint(50.0, 650.0)

    def create_balls(self):
        self.ball[self.i] = self.c.create_oval(self.x-12, self.y-12, self.x+12, self.y+12, fill = 'blue')

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x700')
    root.title('Balls Game')
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    game = Game(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the error is very big but is the same thing repeated several times.
This is the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPcbd.png

Comment: You need to share with us the definition of `Balls`, and also show us the full and complete error message.

Comment: I edit my post, can you see what i did wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does it break?

You shouldn't call .bind every time, you only need to bind an event once at the start, so:

```
    ...
    self.root.bind('<Key>', self.key)
    self.show()
```

is fine.

(Also `self.ball.append([Balls(self.c)])` appends a list with one `Balls` object to the `self.ball` list, and then you call `Balls.create_balls(self)` which might add even more items. Is this desired bahaviour?)